# Assembly XXX which has a higher version than referenced assembly XXX

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, .net-4.5

I am trying to build a project using latest version of Prism and Unity but, it gives below error. How to fix below error?

> Assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.1208.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' c:\Prism4.1\Bin\Desktop\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll   HelloWorld.Desktop

Comment: You need to use a newer version of Unity.

Comment: @Szymon I am using the latest version of Unity from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem between Unity and Prism.

Apparently, when the version of Prism for .NET 4.5 was built they were using a version of Unity signed with a version number of **3.0.1208.0**. However, in the latest releases of Unity it seems that they reset that number back to **3.0.0.0**, which is causing this error as the latest version of Unity has a lower version number that the previous one.

There is a thread in the CodePlex forums for Prism mentioning this with a couple of workarounds for it:

- [Prism 4.5 and Unity 3.0](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/443219)